# Conditional expectations as functions on a triangle

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{M}, P)$ be the probability measure space where $\Omega$ is the set of points in the triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with corners at $(0,0), (2,2)$ and $(0,2)$, $\mathscr{M}$ is the Borel sigma-algebra on $\Omega$ and $P = \frac{1}{2}\lambda$ with $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure. Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables from $\Omega$ to $[0,2]$ with $X(y,x) = x$ and $Y(x,y) = y$. In this problem we are interested in the conditional probability and expectation of $X$, given $Y$, but in a general measure-theoretic language. So first some definitions.

The definition of the conditional probability of a set $A \in \mathscr{M}$ given a subsigma-algebra $\mathscr{B}$ of $\mathscr{M}$ is: it is a function $p : \Omega \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $p$ is measurable with respect to the sigma-algebra $\mathscr{B}$ and for all $B \in \mathscr{B}$ it holds that $E[p \chi_B] = P(A \cap B)$, where $\chi_B$ is the indicator function on $B$ and $E$ is the expectation. We denote this function $p$ by $P(A | \mathscr{B})$. When $Y$ is a random variable, we define $P(A | Y) := P(A | \mathscr{B})$, where $\mathscr{B}$ is the smallest sigma-algebra that makes $Y$ measurable.

Similarly, if $X$ is a real integrable random variable, then the definition of the conditional expectation of $X$ given a subsigma-algebra $\mathscr{B}$ of $\mathscr{M}$ is: it is a function $Z$ which is measurable with respect to $\mathscr{B}$ and for all $B \in \mathscr{B}$ it holds that $E[Z\chi_B] = E[X\chi_B]$. We denote this function $Z$ by $E[X | \mathscr{B}]$ and, again similarly, if $Y$ is a random variable, then we define $E[X | Y] := E[X | \mathscr{B}]$ with $\mathscr{B}$ the smallest sigma-algebra that makes $Y$ measurable.

Now we go back to our setting of the triangle $\Omega$ and the goal is to find the conditional probability $p = P(X \ge 3/4 | Y)$ and the conditional expectation $Z = E[X | Y]$. Therefore, if $\mathscr{B}$ is the smallest sigma-algebra that makes $Y$ measurable, then we are looking for measurable functions $p$ and $Z$ such that for all $B \in \mathscr{B}$ we have $E[p\chi_B] = P(A \cap B)$ where $A$ is the set $\{(x,y) | (x,y) \in \Omega \text{ and } x \ge 3/4\}$ and $E[Z \chi_B] = E[X \chi_B]$.

For $p$ I would propose $p = \max(0, Y - 3/4)$ and for $Z$ I would propose $Z = Y/2$. But I do not know how to verify or prove this, it is just based on intuition. First of all, what is $\mathscr{B}$? I think it is generated by quadrilaterals  of the form $\Omega \cap [0,2] \times [a,b]$ with $0 \le a \le b \le 2$, but I'm not sure. Secondly, how do I prove that the necessary equalities hold for all $B \in \mathscr{B}$?

Any help would be much appreciated.